# Preventing column-class inference in fread()

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

Is there a way for `fread` to mimic the behaviour of `read.table` whereby the `class` of the variable is set by the data that is read in.

I have numeric data with a few comments underneath the main data. When i use `fread` to read in the data, the columns are converted to character. However, by setting the `nrow` in read.table` i can stop this behaviour. Is this possible in fread. (I would prefer not to alter the raw data or make an amended copy). Thanks

An example

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1:100, NA, NA, "fff"), y=c(1:100, NA,NA,NA)) 
write.csv(d, "test.csv",  row.names=F)

in_d <- read.csv("test.csv", nrow=100, header=T)
in_dt <- data.table::fread("test.csv", nrow=100)
```

Which produces

```
> str(in_d)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> str(in_dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

As a workaround I thought i would be able to use `read.table` to read in one line, get the class and set the `colClasses`, but i am misunderstanding.

```
cl <- read.csv("test.csv", nrow=1,  header=T)
cols <- unname(sapply(cl, class))
in_dt <- data.table::fread("test.csv", nrow=100, colClasses=cols)
str(in_dt)
```

Using Windows8.1 
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Sounded  like a reasonable plan but then I actually read the help page: "fread will only promote a column to a higher type if colClasses requests it. It won't downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss." It appears that even limiting the read to 5 rows fails. I think I remember that colClasses mechanism was a fairly recent addition, so maybe you should submit a feature request. Matthew and Arun are often very accomodating.

Comment: Surely there must be a DT strategy to coerce all columns to numeric? Set `.SDcols` to an appropriate vector and something like this: `DT[, .SD := lapply(.SDcols, as.numeric), .SDcols=vec]`. I'm not a DT user but I'm sure there is a minimal-typing approach of some sort and I suspect you can find it illustrated in SO answers.

Comment: @BondedDust; Im not a DT user either, its just read.table is having(more serious) issues with my data than fread is. Ill have a look on SO. thanks

Comment: Look, stop revert-warring your title. It's not about "using nrows". Writing out a string to an integer column is intentionally writing a defective csv. Your issue is ***"Can I prevent data.table's fread column-class inference getting overridden by trailing string comment rows in my data?"*** You know that comment rows should start with a comment-char (like `#`). When we prepend that to your comment text, we get the correct behavior with `read.csv` (but not `fread`). Yes, `fread` could do with an enhance. Meantime needs a workaround.

Comment: thanks for your input. . `"Writing out a string to an integer column is intentionally writing a defective csv."` - this was a `mwe` to reflect some data that i have, and as such it is not commented. If i added `#` to the file it would not reflect the data that i have. btw i didnt revert.

Comment: Ok. Can anyone show (with citation) that this is not an abuse of CSV? Just because `read.csv(nrow)` accepts it and gets the type inference right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Option 1:** Using a system command

`fread()` allows the use of a system command in its first argument. We can use it to remove the quotes in the first column of the file.

```
indt <- data.table::fread("cat test.csv | tr -d '\"'", nrows = 100)
str(indt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

**The system command** `cat test.csv | tr -d '\"'` **explained:**

- `cat test.csv` reads the file to standard output
- `|` is a pipe, using the output of the previous command as input for the next command
- `tr -d '\"'` deletes (`-d`) all occurrences of double quotes (`'\"'`) from the current input

---

**Option 2:** Coercion after reading

Since option 1 doesn't seem to be working on your system, another possibility is to read the file as you did, but convert the `x` column with `type.convert()`.

```
library(data.table)
indt2 <- fread("test.csv", nrows = 100)[, x := type.convert(x)]
str(indt2)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

**Side note:** I usually prefer to use `type.convert()` over `as.numeric()` to avoid the *"NAs introduced by coercion"* warning triggered in some cases.  For example,

```
x <- c("1", "4", "NA", "6")
as.numeric(x)
# [1]  1  4 NA  6
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 
type.convert(x)
# [1]  1  4 NA  6
```

But of course you can use `as.numeric()` as well.

---

**Note:** This answer assumes [data.table dev v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Thanks Richard, however, this throws an error on my system. I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Ive installed the dev version but same error on Windows (works, with helpful warning on linux). Could you explain the system call command please.

Comment: @user2957945 - Okay good to know.  I added a second option that should be sufficiently efficient

Comment: huh... may have spoken too soon on the error using the system call. Actually looks like `fread` doesn't work at all since the dev version. Ill load from cranand see if it fixes. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user2957945 - when you re-do it, use a fresh R session to avoid conflicts with other objects

Comment: Yup, interesting. When i upgrade to the dev version on my system, fread stops working with error `Error in fread("test.csv") : showProgress must be 0 or 1, currently`. Downgrading gets it working again. Your second solution works (always on a fresh session ;))

Answer (score -2):

Ok, the customer is [abusing CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961006/can-a-csv-file-have-a-comment) to intentionally write out trailing string rows to an integer column, yet without those rows starting with a comment.char (`#`).

Then you somehow expect you can override `fread()`'s type inference to read those as integer, by using nrow to try to limit it to just see the integer rows. `read.csv(..., nrow)` will accept this, however `fread()` always uses all rows for type-inference (not just the ones specified by `nrow, skip, header`), and even if they start with comment.char (that's a bug).

1. Sounds like an abuse of CSV. Your comment rows should be prepended with `#`
2. Yes, `fread()` needs a fix/enhance to ignore comment rows for type inference.
3. For now, you can workaround with `fread()` by post-processing the data-table read in.
4. It's arguable whether `fread()` should be changed to support the behavior you want: using nrows to limit what gets exposed to type-inference. It might fix your (pretty unique) case and break some others.

I don't see why you (EDIT: the customer) can't write your comments to a separate `.txt`/README/data-dictionary file to accompany the `.csv`. The practice of using a separate data-dictionary file is pretty well-established.
I've never seen someone do this to a CSV file. At least move the comments to the header, not a footer.

Comment: The csv doesn't have a multi-row header.  It has unwanted stuff at the bottom of the file

Comment: Ok, then trailing (string) comment rows, without any leading '#'. Why did you not just manually append them to the write.csv?

Comment: It's not my question, but I'm guessing that OP already has the file and just used `write.csv()` to create an example.

Comment: Yes as @RichardScriven; said this was a small example of my data and does not have extra headers.or cells with commented characters. It has additional information at the bottom that changes the class of my variables.  We generally store data in non-writable directories (although of course not impossible to get permissions) so i would prefer not to amend and save a new file.

Comment: Re your update: 1) the data is given to me, hence why it is not commented. 3) yes adding this extra information to the bottom is not helpful, but i regularly receive data like this, where clients add small summaries or text below the main data (unfortunately it is not a unique case for me)

Comment: I think your arguments are a little beyond the scope of the question.  Can't we stipulate that this is a bad data format and then ask about how the OP can deal with it? (I know there's a *reductio ad absurdum* here somewhere, e.g. "my customer is embedding their data as a screen capture in a .mp4 file: how can I use `fread` to read it?", but this case seems far from that.)

Comment: PS https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 says nothing whatsoever about comment lines/metadata (except for the header line)

Comment: @Ben Bolker: yes the RFC says nothing whatsoever about comments. The issue of how/whether CSV files can contain comments, and if so in what format, is a longstanding open issue: [Can a CSV file have a comment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961006/can-a-csv-file-have-a-comment)

Comment: @user2957945 if you regularly get such files, then how about writing a script to automatically extract any trailing comment rows (esp. when any of the fields are numeric) and move them to a separate  `.comment` file?