# Read huge .csv file with some columns in single quotes but not all with fread from the data.table package

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I apologize that I cannot really create a reproducible example (or I guess at least not according to the rules) but still hope for help.
I am using the data from here:
[American Housing Survey 2013 data](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/2013/AHS%202013%20Metropolitan%20PUF%20v1.1%20CSV.zip)

Since the data files are quite big I would like to use the "fread" command instead of the "read.csv" command. With read.csv I could just do the following:

```
homimp <- read.csv("homimp.csv", quotes = "'")
head(homimp)
       CONTROL RAS RAH  RAD JRAS JRAD
1 100003130103  74   2   96   -9    9
2 100006110249  35   2 8358   -9    9
3 100006110249  36   2 5970   -9    9
4 100006110249  37   2 6567   -9    9
5 100006110249  40   2  716   -9    9
6 100006110249  45   2 1910   -9    9
```

and it would remove the quotes (note that one column (RAD) is not in quotes in the first place)
However, if I read with fread I do not seem to be able to remove the quotes
The quote argument returns an error:

```
homimpdt <- fread("homimp.csv", quote = "'")
Error in fread("homimp.csv", quote = "'") : unused argument (quote = "'")
```

And without the argument quotes are not removed:

```
homimpdt <- fread("homimp.csv")
head(homimpdt)
          CONTROL  RAS RAH  RAD JRAS JRAD
1: '100003130103' '74' '2'   96 '-9'  '9'
2: '100006110249' '35' '2' 8358 '-9'  '9'
3: '100006110249' '36' '2' 5970 '-9'  '9'
4: '100006110249' '37' '2' 6567 '-9'  '9'
5: '100006110249' '40' '2'  716 '-9'  '9'
6: '100006110249' '45' '2' 1910 '-9'  '9'
```

Why I want to do this:

```
> system.time(newhouse <- read.csv('newhouse.csv', quote = "'"))
   user  system elapsed 
  24.86    0.68   25.77 
> system.time(newhousedt <- fread('newhouse.csv'))
Read 84355 rows and 760 (of 760) columns from 0.273 GB file in 00:00:04
   user  system elapsed 
   3.33    0.07    3.41
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Ad Psidom's comment:

```
homimpdt <- fread("homimp.csv", quote = "\'")
Error in fread("homimp.csv", quote = "'") : unused argument (quote = "'")
```

Comment: Set `quote = "\'"`.

Comment: @ Psidom: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it also returns an error.

Comment: There is no `quote` parameter for `data.table::fread()` unless you use 1.9.7 from github but this file is ~67K lines. That's not a big file and really doesn't warrant the use of `fread()` for "speed"

Comment: Oh I forget that I am using `data.table` 1.9.7.

Comment: @ hrbrmstr Thanks for your answer! Is there anything I could use instead to remove the quotes or is this simply not possible with fread?

Comment: @ Psidom: I am using 1.9.6 (This is what Rstudio installed). So I guess the update will fix that?

Comment: install the github version of `data.table` if you really want to but none of those CSV files are large. Even `person.csv` is small data.

Comment: You can update your data.table package, as my testing goes, it works with `1.9,7`, it is still under development though, so use it with caution.

Comment: Alright thank you both! It would just save me some time. ;) (edit: I guess if its still in dev I will wait for the update. I value the stability of the package more than my time) btw: is there any way I can give you credit for your answers? I understand usually one can check an answer as correct?

Comment: @DanielWinkler installing 1.9.7 is pretty simple `install.packages("data.table", type="source", repos="http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")`, in case of any problems [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) is full description.

Comment: You might try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499145/preventing-column-class-inference-in-fread/29499512#29499512 if you are on a linux-based system.  Actually, the `type.convert` part (option 2) would probably work here as well.

Comment: @jangorecki Thank you very much for the instructions! Seems fairly straightforward! :)

Comment: @RichScriven Thank you! I am currently on Windows 10 but I'll try when I get to my Linux PC (unfortunately I am sharing this code with Windows-only users). As for option two: as.numeric introduces NAs and type.convert makes the variable a factor but I will toy around a bit with that.

Comment: No worries.  `as.is = TRUE` in `type.convert()` will prevent factor coercion.

Comment: Now that when it looks like that you have got solution running; consider changing the question. Plus if anyone else (among commenters) don't do it consider wrapping up the question with summary of the comments above :)

Comment: Thank you @RichScriven and @abhiieor!! Is it possible to flag the question as solved even though there are no "answers" but only comments? Should I sum up the solution in the question or "answer" it with the solution?

Comment: Glad to help!  Yes, you could write up your own answer based on the information we helped you gather.  It's perfectly acceptable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the answers given in comments:

Solution #1:
Thanks to @Psidom and @jangorecki

Install data.table v. 1.9.7:

```
install.packages("data.table", type="source", repos="http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

Then run:

```
homimpdt <- fread("homimp.csv", quote = "\'")
```

EDIT: Current version of data.table on CRAN is 1.9.6

Solution #2 (linux only):
thanks to @RichScriven

can be found here:
[Preventing column-class inference in fread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499145/preventing-column-class-inference-in-fread/29499512#29499512)

and set `as.is = TRUE` in the `type.convert()` function