# Insert into any file something to recognize

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I've created for my company a webapp that let company clients make queries against a database and get the output as a table. At this point they can export and download on own pc this table in .csv or .xlsx (the export is made by javascript code).

My company wants to prevent malicious clients reselling this files so I wanted to know if it's possible insert into these files an invisible identifier (as a metatag) to recoignize them to aim counteract industrial espionage or similar violations over this files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961006/can-a-csv-file-have-a-comment

Comment: Not with a CSV file, as it's basically a text file that can be opened and edited, plus you can't "hide" anything in it.  It may be possible to so something with an xls/xlsx file, but realistically once someone has the data then they have the data.  All you can do is make it more difficult to be abused, but they'll always have copy/paste.  I'd suggest putting some identifying data in there that looks like just another row of data, but for you it can identify who downloaded it.  Just a suggestion, but food for thought.

Comment: Isn't a way to modifiy binary of file or similar things? I've never made these things before so excuse the question.